# How can I parse a period of date into a String[ ] day by day in Java?

Tags: java

For example,the input parameters are 2011-01-01 and 2012-01-01,
and I want to parse this period day by day like 2011-01-01~2011-01-02, 2011-01-02~2011-01-03...
Finally,store them in a array of String?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking for - can you provide more detail, and perhaps show what code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing the date from a string, I recommend using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

That way you will obtain a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. Use the Date object to create a [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

Then, you can use GregorianCalendar's `add` method to increase it one day at a time until you reach your end date.

Here's a code example:

```
String dateString1 = "2011-01-01";
String dateString2 = "2012-01-01";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();

Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString1);
Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString2);

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(startDate);
while (calendar.getTime().before(endDate)) {
    dates.add(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

This puts your dates in a list. You can convert it to an array like this:

```
String[] datesArray = dates.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really work on your accept rate. but the basic method would go like this :

psuedo-code:

```
Date first = "2011-01-01";
Date last = "2012-01-01";
Calendar cal = new Calendar(first);
List<Date> dates = ...;

while (first.before(last)) {
    cal.addDays(1);
    dates.add(cal);    
}
```

This should be really easy to implement using `GregorianCalendar`, or you can check out [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which would make this a whole lot of easy...